# How to configure Java -D flag in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

For example:

```
java -Dcom.siebel.management.jmxapi.cfgFileName=C:\monitor\1srvr.xml Component
```

Where (in Eclipse) do I configure the -D flag with the name and the value?
`Component` is a class file.

When I run my code in Eclipse, I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Configuration file name must be specified in com.siebel.management.jmxapi.cfgFileName system property
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.siebel.management.jmxapi.JmxComponent.getState(JmxComponent.java:169)
    at Component.main(Component.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configuration file name must be specified in com.siebel.management.jmxapi.cfgFileName system property
    at com.siebel.management.jmxapi.SiebelAgentUtil.<init>(SiebelAgentUtil.java:78)
    at com.siebel.management.jmxapi.SiebelAgentUtil.<clinit>(SiebelAgentUtil.java:43)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of easy ways to do this in Eclipse.

1) From the very top bar select **Run->Run Configurations**

or

2) Right click your project and select **Run As->Run Configurations**

Next, the common step is to select your project class(those that contain main method) in the left pane and in the corresponding neighboring pane on the right choose **Arguments**

Set the desired arguments(**Program or VM arguments**)

Comment: According to my experience, `-D` flags should go to **VM arguments** in full form, i.e. including the initial `-D`.

Answer (score 0):

**Editing the vm args of eclipse**

Under the directory where eclipse has been installed you can find a file named eclipse.ini. Edit it to add additional parameters under the `vmargs` section.

**Example**

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

**Editing the vm args of an application inside eclipse**

If you want to edit this for an application that is run from eclipse, you'll need to provide the information under the [arguments tab](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Farguments.htm).

Comment: I suppose he rather wants it for an application he's building/running from eclipse, not eclipse itself.

Comment: sorry,it didn't work, i still get the exception in the question

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @nos. I assumed it must've been a Siebel plugin for eclipse. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I did:

```
System.setProperty("com.siebel.management.jmxapi.cfgFileName", "C:\\siebelmonitor\\1srvr.xml");
```