# Flink Retrofit not Serializable Exception

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink Job reading events from a Kafka queue then calling another service if certain conditions are met.
I wanted to use Retrofit2 to call the REST endpoint of that service but I get a is not Serializable Exception. I have several Flat Maps connected to each other (in series) then calling the service happens in the last FlatMap. The exception I get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The
>   implementation of the RichFlatMapFunction is not serializable. The
>   object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: retrofit2.Retrofit$1
>   ...

The way I am initializing retrofit:

```
RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(NotificationService.class);
```

And the NotificationService interface

```
public interface NotificationService {

    @PUT("/test")
    Call<String> putNotification(@Body Notification notification);
}
```

The RetrofitClient class

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your Notification class code for more details, but looks like this answer helps 
[java.io.NotSerializableException with "$1" after class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325873/java-io-notserializableexception-with-1-after-class)

Comment: But I did, it's an interface.

Comment: You added NotificationService interface but looks like problem in this line  Call<String> putNotification(@Body Notification notification); you add in body of request Notification class, looks like problem in it. So could you add Notification class source

Comment: public class Notification implements Serializable {
  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   

  private String id;
  
  private String text;

  getters & setters here
}

Comment: In fact I replaced the Notification with String and adapted the code now, still getting the same Exception.

Comment: Oh clear. You try to serialise Retrofit class. But first item pf retrofit class: public final class Retrofit {
  private final Map<Method, ServiceMethod<?, ?>> serviceMethodCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); java.lang.reflect.Method can't be serialiized.